# I am converting NSString a=@"0x401A" into int16_t?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, ios-bluetooth

Why when I am trying to convert it converts hexadecimal value into integer?

```
unsigned int outVal;
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:final1];
[scanner scanHexInt:&outVal];
NSLog(@"%u",outVal);
```

Another way I am trying to do is converting it to normal **integer** it gives me **0** value.
I just want the same characters:

```
int16_t a=0x401A;
```

I am getting this number from user so dont have the control to define it myself. I want removed quotations and datatype **int16_t** so I can execute command.

Comment: If you use a hex format (@"%X") in `NSLog` do you see the right value?

Comment: yes i see the right value, but i need this in integer to pass the command to BLE device

Comment: You're missing the point.  The integer has the right numeric value; whether you see it as hex or decimal is only a function of the format string you use in `NSLog()`.

Comment: but BLE device only accepts command in 0x401A in this format. If i convert this hex into integer then i miss this '0x' then bluetooth device thinks wrong command.

Comment: The '0x' is part of a string.  It's not part of an integer value.  If the device needs to see '0x' in the command, then it's expecting you to send a string.

Comment: but normally i am sending the command like int16_t=0x401A works perfectly for me. It doesn't expect the string to be honest.

Comment: One more try...run this and see if it gives you any ideas:
 `int16_t a=0x401A;
 NSLog(@"0x401A = %u", a);
 
 int16_t b=16410;
 NSLog(@"16410 = 0x%X", b);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution myself

first the function which converts the data into bytes

```
    - (NSData *)dataWithString:(NSString *)hexstring
{
    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData data];
    int idx;
    for (idx = 0; idx+2 <= hexstring.length; idx+=2) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(idx, 2);
        NSString* hexStr = [hexstring substringWithRange:range];
        NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexStr];
        unsigned int intValue;
        [scanner scanHexInt:&intValue];
        [data appendBytes:&intValue length:1];
    }
    return data;
}
```

and call the function by giving parameters in the command which will be sent to BLE

```
NSData * data = [self  dataWithString: @"401A"];
[peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic                                       
                            type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

Through this code anybody can sent string to BLE device. Thanks and Cheers